# How to define an assert function receive unlimited parameter and print them

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-preprocessor, assert

I have defined an assert function, just to print the function name and line number, but I get Segmentation fault (core dumped), how to fix it?

```
#define assert( string ) \
    printf("%s - %s assert %s\n",__FUNCTION__, __LINE__,  #string);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert( "test assert" );
    printf("%s(%d)-%s: this is main\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

the ultimate target is to define the function to print all the info passed by parameter like `printf` receive unlimited parameters.

Comment: `__LINE__` is an `int`, not a string.  You need to use it with `%d`, not `%s`.  Also, `#string` *stringizes* the argument, but you're already passing it a string.  This question also doesn't have anything to do with receiving an unlimited number of arguments...

Comment: Thanks! @Paul Rooney solves all my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your question I've assumed you are asking for an assert macro.

When you assert you assert on a condition being true or false. You don't just pass it a string.

Try this

```
#define ASSERT(cond_, fmt, ...) do                              \
                    {                                           \
                        if(!(cond_))                            \
                        {                                       \
                            printf("assert: file %s line %d ",  \
                            __FILE__, __LINE__);                \
                            fprintf(stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);  \
                            fflush(stderr);                     \
                            abort();                            \
                        }                                       \
                    } while(0)
```

For gcc the `fprintf` line must be defined as

```
fprintf(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);  \
```

It is a good strategy however to define your assert functionality as a function and wrap this function in a macro.

- The macro facilitates easy disabling of the assert in a release build.
- The function gives you a great place to put a breakpoint when debugging.

Comment: Why the `do... while()` loop when it just runs only once?

Comment: @binaryBaBa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros